# Why ruby adds an empty element to an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question I just can't figure it out. I have 2 models in Ruby on Rails project - Project and Page. Page belongs to a Project, and Project has multiple Pages.

In rails console when I do `Page.where(project_id: 25)` I receive 4 results and that is correct. But in my contoller when I do

```
@project = Project.find(25)
@all_pages = @project.pages
```

For some reason @all_pages is an array of 5 elements. The last element is empty

```
<Page id: nil, name: nil, project_id: 25, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, parent_page_id: nil, weight: nil>
```

I can't figure out why an empty element appears. Could you help me to figure it out? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here is more data from my models\controllers

Models:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :parent_page, class_name: "Page"
  has_many :sub_pages, class_name: "Page", foreign_key: "parent_page_id"
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

  default_scope { order('weight ASC') }

  before_create :set_weight

  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_presence_of :name

  def set_weight
    self.weight = Project.find(self.project_id).pages.maximum("weight").to_i + 1 
  end

end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :pages, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :project_roles, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :project_roles

  #validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_length_of :name, minimum: 5

end
```

Controllers:

```
  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @all_pages = @project.pages
    @page = Page.find(params[:id]) 
  end
```

And then in my View I'm using it like this:

```
<%= select_tag(:parent_page_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@all_pages, "id", "name"), { :class => 'form-control' }) %>
```

And this renders a list of 5 elements instead of 4 and the last one is empty.

Comment: Could you show us Project model?

Comment: Does it persist after a restart? The lack of `id` of that empty `Page` suggests it has not been saved in the database at all. Perhaps you accidentally created it during tests.

Comment: Can you show us more code: How you defined the associations in the models, your controller methods, perhaps the view and the helper (if you have logic in them)?

Comment: Updated my question with more details (models\views\controllers)